# How to show pattern validation error when control looses focus - Angular 2

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms, formbuilder

I made a form using FormBuilder approach. Now I want to add some pattern validation.

I added the validation and it is working fine. But the validation error is showing at non desired time.

I have added one `textfield` and added a `pattern` validation. I wanted to show the error message when another control get selected or it looses focus.
But currently the validation error is showing as soon as I start entering text.

Can I show the error message in lost focus event. I know I can easily do it by binding a method in `onChange` event of `TextControl` but If there is another approach I will love to know that.

[Here is the Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZeuDzHs257sQBomc9gEh?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it subscribe valuechange on particular one control valuechanges.

**for Example**
**

> **first method**

```
 import...
    @Component({..})
    export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

         ngOnInit(): void {
                this.formName.get('name')
                    .valueChanges
                    .filter((value: string) => value != null && value.length > 0) // use filter if needed otherwise remove it
                    .subscribe((value: string) => {
                         if (!value.match(/[-!$%^&*(/]/... set here your pettern)) {
                                  this.formName.controls.name.setErrors({});
                             }
                    }

            }
        }
```

> **second method**

***html***

```
<input type='text' (blur)="checkValidation()" formControlName="name">
```

{{errorMessage}}

***Method in component***

```
import...
    @Component({..})
    export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage ='';
         ngOnInit(): void {

            }

      checkValidation(): void {
            if (!value.match(/[-!$%^&*(/]/... set here your pettern)) {
                this.formName.controls.name.setErrors({});
                 this.errorMessage = 'set here your message';
              }
        }
```

Comment: Yes I know this method. I am interested in `blur` event. How can I show the error message when control loses focus @Shalesh

Comment: Your code is working fine. Can I do same by using only classes as in Plunker.